# Laravel VueQuerybuilder addfilter() how to change lable

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I used laravel vue query builder. For filter option i used the below code

```
 return  Inertia::render('Speaker/List', [
      'users'=>$users,
    ])->table(function ($table) use ($degreeArr, $ProductArr) {
        $table->addFilter('products.id', '', $ProductArr);
    });


<Table
        :filters="queryBuilderProps.filters"
        :search="queryBuilderProps.search"
        :columns="queryBuilderProps.columns"
        :on-update="setQueryBuilder"
        :meta="users"
      >
       <template v-slot:tableFilter="slotProps">
        <div v-for="filter in slotProps.filters" :key="filter.key">
        <!-- <h3 class="text-xs uppercase tracking-wide bg-gray-100 p-3">{{filter.label}}</h3> -->
        <div class="px-4">
          <select
            :value="filter.value"
            @change="slotProps.changeFilterValue(filter.key, $event.target.value)"
            class="block focus:ring-indigo-500 h-11 focus:border-indigo-500 w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
          >
            <option v-for="(option, key) in filter.options" :value="key" :key="key">{{ option }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      </template>
```

I gives the output fine as

```
<select class="block ">
<option value="1">Test1</option>
<option value="2">Test2</option>
<option value="3">Test3</option>
<option value="">-</option>
</select>
```

Here in last option the - value is added. Here I want to Change the "-" as "All". Or how do I remove the last option ("-").

Comment: How is Inertia rendering the select?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy I have updated the code .

Comment: Can't you remove the value from your `filter.options` before looping through it?

Comment: Its dynamically updated as the last option.